# Unable to obtain authorization token for partner community users

Tags: community, oauth2, apexrest, lightning-community, partner-communities

I have exposed an apex class as a rest service. I want my community users to be able to use the rest service to insert records in the system. I have set up a connected app to enable access using Oauth.

I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_auth_configure_oauth.htm&type=5). The guide mentions the request format to be of the form

```
https://acme.force.com/customers/services/oauth2/authorize?​response_type=token&client_id=your_app_id&redirect_uri=your_redirect_uri
```

My resultant url was of form :

```
https://xxxxx-xxxxxxxx.xx6.force.com/xxxxcommunity/services/oauth2/authorize?​response_type=token&client_id=my_consumer_key&redirect_uri=connected_app_callback_url
```

This resulted in `error=unsupported_response_type&error_description=response%20type%20not%20supported`

I then tried using the [AxiomSSO](https://axiomsso.herokuapp.com/OAuth2WebFlowTester.action) heroku app. This generated a URL of the form :

```
https://xxxxxx.force.com/omplcommunity/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&display=popup&client_id=my_consumer_key&redirect_uri=connected_app_callback_url
```

On requesting authorization code, it opens up a page titled 'Login Template' which then changes to 'Login but is blank. I was expecting my community's login page but the page is entirely blank. I would deeply appreciate any help regarding this.

Additional Info if it matters :

1. At profile level, I've given the System Permission - 'Api Enabled', Apex class has been appropriately enabled along with the connected app.
2. The custom app has 'Require Secret for Web Server Flow' checked
3. I am able to use the web service using users with standard salesforce license.

Comment: Are you deliberately putting "response_type=token" because this is different flow for desktop or mobile which does not require client secret? If it's web app then response type should be 'code'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copy and paste URLs or URL fragments from `help.salesforce.com`, you might copy an invisible control character that represents a continuation of two lines. On Windows, this control character is a [left-to-right mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark). In UTF-8 this control character is `E2 80 8E` or `%E2%80%8B` when URL-encoded. When you paste a URL into some tool and/or browser, depending on the tool and/or browser configuration, you may not see the character because it's, well, invisible.

URL with the control character:

`.../services/oauth2/authorize?%E2%80%8Bresponse_type=token&client_id=my_consumer_key&redirect_uri=connected_app_callback_url`

Running this URL against any Saleforce token endpoint will correctly produce `error=unsupported_response_type`

Correct URL without the control character:

`.../services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=my_consumer_key&redirect_uri=connected_app_callback_url`

Bonus: don't use the implicit grant type (`response_type=token`), it's [no longer considered secure](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273714/oauth-2-0-user-agent-flow-why-is-it-okay-to-keep-the-refresh-token-when-it-is-c)

Comment: I tried copying pasting the correct URL you posted in your answer. Ensured there was nothing additional and it still takes me to a blank page titled "Login". I still do not see my community's login page.

Comment: @N_H1922 Blank login page is a different issue, likely related to the way you configured community login options..but could be something else too. This flow works for us with an out of the box community. You might want to create a new question instead of combining multiple questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!