# Is it possible to return CORS headers (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) on 401 Unauthorized responses?

Tags: rest-api, api, rest, cors

I've enabled CORS and am using My Domain to successfully make REST API requests from a browser, after getting an Access Token via the User-Agent flow. My goal is to also use the Refresh Token to automatically get a new Access Token once the initial one is invalid.

The problem I've having is that I can't detect when the Salesforce REST API returns a 401 Unauthorized response because the CORS headers aren't returned when Access Token is not valid.

For my specific implementation, I've configured [axios-auth-refresh](https://github.com/Flyrell/axios-auth-refresh) to automatically get a new Access Token when a 401 response is detected per (brand new) [instructions in ts-force](https://cjonas.gitbook.io/ts-force/v/3.0/guides/connecting-with-salesforce/re-auth-on-token-expiration). However, this question isn't strictly related to either of those.

Here's an example with a valid access token where you can see the CORS response headers coming back along with the response:

```
curl 'https://[my domain].my.salesforce.com/services/data/v50.0/composite/batch' \
  --verbose \
  -H $'Authorization: Bearer [...]' \
  -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8080' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-binary $'{"batchRequests":[{"method":"GET","url":"v50.0/query?q=SELECT%20Id%20FROM%20Account%20LIMIT%201"}]}' \
  2>&1 | grep '< HTTP\|< Access-Control\|{"'
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
{"hasErrors":false,"results":[{"statusCode":200,"result":
{"totalSize":1,"done":true,"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/Account/[...]"},"Id":"[...]"}]}}]}
```

With an invalid access token, the result is the following (no `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers present):

```
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
```

Is there any way to get Salesforce to return the appropriate CORS headers for an invalid or expired Access Token, or is the only option here to set up a proxy, or add logic to refresh the token on any kind of AJAX error (instead of being able to detect a 401)?

Comment: _The only option here to set up a proxy, or add logic to refresh the token on any kind of AJAX error_  - sounds like you've answered your own question. You might want to rethink your choice of flow: [User-Agent isn't recommended nowadays](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273714/oauth-2-0-user-agent-flow-why-is-it-okay-to-keep-the-refresh-token-when-it-is-c).

Comment: In my case, I need the user to be authenticated with their own account (so that modifications are attributed to them and permissions are enforced), and there is currently no backend, so all code needs to run on the frontend safely and without the client secret. Since Salesforce does have support for CORS, it didn't make sense that CORS headers wouldn't be returned with a 401. I wasn't sure if the behavior I was observing was expected, or if there was some other configuration I missed that could remedy this so CORS would work with a 401 in my org.

Comment: _I need the user to be authenticated with their own account (so that modifications are attributed to them and permissions are enforced), and there is currently no backend, so all code needs to run on the frontend safely and without the client secret_ - authorization code grant (aka Web Server flow) does all of this. _Since Salesforce does have support for CORS, it didn't make sense that CORS headers wouldn't be returned with a 401_ - maybe...but that's not an oAuth issue per se. The remedy is to do a proxy or build your own logic as you correctly figured.

Comment: Are you referring to this [Web Server Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5)? I haven't used that yet, but the docs indicate *the server hosting the web app must be able to protect the connected app’s identity, defined by the client ID and client secret*, so it didn't see like this would work in an untrusted environment where you couldn't expose the client secret (like the browser). For a workaround I have refresh working on *any* network failure (coarse but it works). Since simplicity and latency is a priority, a proxy isn't desirable.

Comment: The client secret can be made optional as Web Server flow doc states.